# Navigation Bar not appearing in iPhone 7

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

Im facing an issue where the navigation bar is not appearing in iPhone 7(os - 11.0.2). The nav bar is coming simulator 7. The nav is appearing in other devices running in iOS 11.0.2. Issue is in iPhone 7.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.StoryBoardIdentifiers.mainStoryboard, bundle: nil)
let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryBoardIdentifiers.SummaryViewController) as! SummaryViewController

let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

let slideController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:navigationController, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)
slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorSignUp") as! SignUpViewController

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

try this one....

Comment: i have added this in appdelegate.

Comment: try once time 
added this in viewcontroller viwedidload.